# In C++ standard document, how to know the range where subscript "opt" has an effect?

Tags: c++

This is a general question which asks how to read and understand C++ standard document. What I want to know is not the syntax of the constructor initializer. Actually I know it.

---

I'm reading [N3092](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf). In section 12.6.2, syntax of a constructor initializer is explained as below.

> ctor-initializer:
>         : mem-initializer-list
>
> mem-initializer-list:
>         mem-initializer ... <sub>*opt*</sub>
>         mem-initializer , mem-initializer-list ... <sub>*opt*</sub>
>
> mem-initializer:
>         mem-initializer-id ( expression-list opt )
>         mem-initializer-id braced-init-list
>
> mem-initializer-id:
>         class-or-decltype
>         identifier

Now, in thinking about

> mem-initializer ... <sub>*opt*</sub>

, how can you know the range where the subscript "<sub>*opt*</sub>" has an effect? Only three dots "...", or "mem-initializer ..." as a whole?

Because the code below cannot be compiled, you can "confirm" the subscript acts on the three dots "...".

```
class Example {
    public:
        Example() : { } //=> Error: colon should be omitted.
};
```

So you may rewrite as this, where parenthesis () is grouping.

> mem-initializer ((...) <sub>*opt*</sub>)

Next, think about the alternative expression.

> mem-initializer , mem-initializer-list ... <sub>*opt*</sub>

A simple check tells you that you should read this as this.

> mem-initializer ((, mem-initializer-list ... )<sub>*opt*</sub>)

For example, this code cannot be compiled.

```
class Example {
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        Example() : x(3), { } //=> Error: comma should be omitted.
};
```

Then, how is the range defined? (OPTIONAL: Also, I think the meaning of three dots is ambiguous. In what page of the document is three-dot defined?)

Though section 1.6-1 says

> An optional terminal or nonterminal symbol is indicated by the subscript "<sub>*opt*</sub>"

, but I don't think this solve my question (or perhaps I don't understand the terminal/non-terminal symbol).

Comment: "opt" only applies to the immediately preceding symbol. In "_mem-initializer_ **,** _mem-initializer-list_ **...** [opt]", "opt" only applies to the ellipsis (otherwise `x(3)` would match two grammar rules).

Comment: @cpplearner If so, what does the ellipsis represent in "*mem-initializer*, *mem-initializer-list* ... [opt]"? Does it include comma? (Otherwise I think `x(3), y(3) z(3)` is valid. But this is invalid.) If so, why? BTW, thinking twice, now it seems the first expression "*mem-initializer* ...[opt]" itself is also strange, because there is no comma.

Comment: The ellipsis represents a literal ellipsis `...`. It indicates a [pack expansion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Base_specifiers_and_member_initializer_lists).

Comment: @cpplearner Thank you very much. Now I feel the syntax explanation is natural.

Comment: Re the "..." -- if you look **really carefully** you'll see that the "..." is in code font, i.e., it's a literal. If that's not obvious to you, don't kick yourself; it's subtle.

Comment: @PeteBecker "Aha! Those dots look like they're from a slab-serif font!"

Comment: @Sneftel -- if I remember correctly (I was project editor for C++ 11 and wrote the original LaTeX macros that do that), it's bold monospace sans-serif.